# Grails 2.2.3 : Logging - Log from Java Classes from All Packages into a log file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, grails-2.2

I have successfully configured logging in **Grails 2.2.3**
My log file has logs from all grails artifacts.

But I am trying to to get Logs from my Java Classes. I have defined

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
```

with this I do get Logging info on the Console, but It does not log into Logging file.
I am using Java classes from external **jar.**
Do note that all my **Groovy** and **Java** classes are under the **package structure**

Example:-

- com.example.fileupload
- com.example.imagedownload
- com.example.datacapturing
- com.example.videoprocess

etc.

My Config.groovy configuration is as follows to get info and error related logs from Groovy and Java classes

```
info 'com.example'
error 'com.example'
```

I am able to get Groovy Classes log informations in logging file but not the Java Classes.

Please let me know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on a random side note: java packages should be named all lowercase.

Comment: are you really calling first `info` and then `error`?

Comment: @cfrick for java packages I know they should be lowercase and in the application they are ok. and for calling info and error. I tried either way calling error first and than info. Still I did not work

Comment: @cfrick just edited java package names.

Comment: what do you expect from calling it two times?  it can only be one

Comment: I have log.info() and log.error() statements in Java Classes, I just want both to be logged in a Log file, Which is not logging into the log file even after putting error before info in Config.groovy

Comment: Please try only `info 'com.example'`

Comment: I just did, but no outcome :(